# Angular - My $resource .query value's characters are being sent as separate parameters, why?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

In my Angular.js app, when I send a query via my $resource .query method, the characters of the query string are being submitted as separate parameters.  Why is this happening?

Here is the result:

```
cities?0=n&1=e&2=w&3=y&4=o&country_code=US
```

Here is my code:

```
// Cities service used REST endpoint
angular.module('mean.cities').factory("Cities", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('cities/:query', {
        query:'@query',
        country_code: 'US'
    }, 
    {});
}]);


// Controller Method
$scope.autocompleteCity = function(query) {
        Cities.query($scope.query, function(cities) {
            console.log(cities);
        });
};

// UI Element
<input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="query" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter A Town" ng-change="autocompleteCity()">
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngResource`'s static methods expect first parameter to be an object.

Working code:

```js
Cities.query({query: $scope.query}, function(cities) {
  // Makes GET request to /cities/washington?country_code=US given the query value of "washington"
  console.log(cities);
});
```